# Rewind a SKPhysicsWorld

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, multiplayer, latency, game-development

Lets say I have a SKScene with no gravity, and a single sprite that has been given an impulse and is slowly moving it's way through that SKScene.  Lets say I'm at the 10 second mark, and I'd like to see where my sprite would be if I had given it a nudge at the 5 second mark.  In otherwords, I'd like to quickly rewind the scene to the 5 second mark, apply an impulse, and then quickly fast forward it back to the 10 second mark.  Ideally, the user wouldn't need to see this activity, it would just be a jump to the new position/vector of the sprite.

The problem I'm trying to solve here is how to do a persistent MMO 2d space game using Sprite Kit and a Websocket server.  And I'm a little bit stuck on how to keep all the players in sync with each other and still have relatively latency free play.  I considered:

1. Game Kit -- Not enough players, not persistent
2. Client sends commands (thrust, turn, etc) and Server manages physics, responding with new location / vector

   - If I send constant position updates for all objects, this doesn't seem efficient, as in space all objects will constantly be moving / rotating so this will result in a huge stream.
   - If I send updated vectors, local objects will be constantly stuttering and jumping around as the amount of latency per each update will be variable based on network latency
3. Client sends commands, Server records the commands, gives them an official timestamp, and sends the commands down to the client, client then matches the official timestamp with their own running time code, rewind their local physics to the time the command was sent, make the related change and then fast forward back to where the user was.  This might result in a single ship jumping a little bit but could be smoother.